# Program fails after compiling properly

Tags: c, command-prompt

I have written a simple loop in C which is meant to print n^2 given N from the user. It crashes after inputting N. I've removed the loop and it still crashes when all I am now doing is using scanf to input N. Here is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int n;
    int N;

    printf("Input iterations: ");
    scanf("%d", N);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using a gcc compiler, and compiling it using command prompt (Windows 10), with the following command:

```
gcc "C2 Loops.c" -o "C2 Loops.exe"
```

It compiles fine, and then runs when I enter:

```
"C2 Loops.exe"
```

but as soon as I enter the value for N, the program crashes:

[Crash message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8APS9.png)
[Crash message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWRbJ.png)

As a side note (I usually program in C++) adding
    using namespace std;
throws an error on compilation. Is that normal?

Any help with this problem would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do not just provide links. All necessary information has to be included in the question! And read the `scanf` manpage!

Comment: You should always compile with -Wall and take the warnings seriously.

Comment: You should also read the relevant manuals. google "man scanf" or, if on Cygwin, just type "man scanf".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", N);
           ^ missing &
```

`%d` expects address of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the address of the variable to `scanf()`, not the variable itself. Change

`scanf("%d", N);`

to

`scanf("%d", &N);`

Otherwise, `scanf` will try to set the input value to the address which `N` points to. The value of `N` isn't initialized here, means the program will accsess the unpredictable memory address here. That's why your program failed.

Answer (score 0):

Only with this part of code, the program recive the parameter N and end. Becouse you don`t do nothing with this parameter. Maybe you should show us how do you writed to print n^2 command. That it could be something like

```
printf("N^2 = %d", N*N);
```